# htaccess http-to-https redirect not affecting root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This one's been bugging me for a while now. We're trying to redirect from `http://` to `https://` and from `ourdomain.co.uk` to `www.ourdomain.co.uk`.

Both the `https` and `www` redirects work for every page. *BUT* the `https` is not applied when accessing the root url, `http://www.ourdomain.co.uk`.

`http://ourdomain.co.uk` gets redirected to `https://...` without any problems.

What could be causing this? I'm a `.htaccess` n00b, but everything we're using matches all the suggestions I've found by searching for the problem...

This is the start of our `.htaccess`:

```
# FIX for Wordpress menu limit
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_input_vars 6000
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Force traing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

### more page-by-page redirects go here ###
```